# Removing rows from a df that contain same combination of 2 columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I have a df as below that contains combinations of ids, how can I remove the same combinations? For ex. the first 4 rows are the same combination ,but just in different order. Is there a way I can remove all duplicate combinations when they are in different order but keeping the one unique combination?

```
Name  ID1  Time  ID2  Time
Chi 232 24:18.4 111 19:17.7
Chi 111 19:17.7 232 24:18.4
Ari 444 02:33.0 555 57:34.2
Ari 555 57:34.2 444 02:33.0
Ca  321 27:11.7 787 22:14.5
Ca  443 42:49.4 667 47:47.4
Ca  667 47:47.4 443 42:49.4
```

Comment: Are both columns really named `ID`?  You shouldn't have duplicate column names

Comment: Sorry the first is called ID1 and 2nd is ID2 @user3483203

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort your `ID` columns to create a mask with `duplicated`, then index your DataFrame.

```
u = df.filter(like='ID').values
m = pd.DataFrame(np.sort(u, axis=1)).duplicated()

df[~m]
```

```
  Name  ID1    Time1   ID2    Time2
0  Chi  232  24:18.4   111  19:17.7
2  Ari  444  02:33.0   555  57:34.2
4   Ca  321  27:11.7   787  22:14.5
5   Ca  443  42:49.4   667  47:47.4
```

Comment: Question - there are other rows in the column ID that contain the same ID duplicate value,  like 232 but will be combo with a different id. This wont remove the same ID from the same column right?

For example the 111 232 combo is gone, but I dont want to remove all other values in the column that have 232 bc they could be matched with a totally different ID. @newuser3483203

Comment: This only removes duplicated combinations, 232 would not be removed unless its combination was also found in another column

Comment: Thanks ! @user3483203